# Robust detection of module name of Python egg

Tags: python, egg

Lets say I make an egg

```
~/toolz$ python setup.py bdist_egg
creating 'dist/toolz-0.7.4-py3.4.egg'
```

How do I detect the module name of this egg?  Will it always be the word preceding the version string?

```
>>> egg_name = 'toolz-0.7.4-py3.4.egg'
>>> egg_name.split('-')[0]
'toolz'
```

Or does this fail sometimes?  Is there a library I should use for this instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: import pkg_resources

In [2]: pkgs = list(pkg_resources.find_distributions('dist/toolz-0.7.4-py2.7.egg'))

In [3]: assert len(pkgs) == 1

In [4]: pkg = pkgs[0]

In [5]: pkg.project_name
Out[5]: 'toolz'
```